# Formatted strings in Android aren't displayed correctly before first update from ViewModel/LiveData

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have some strings defined in `/res/values/strings.xml` as usual, and I was experimenting with formatting and HTML styling. As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#formatting-strings) and [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML), they're all defined like this

```
<string name="my_string">&lt;b>stuff in bold&lt;/b> %1$s</string>
```

and to show them on screen I must do this:

```
myTextView.text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.my_string, "first argument"), FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

In the end I should be able to see "**stuff in bold** first argument" on screen, but the argument is actually supplied by a ViewModel whenever its LiveData changes, so in my fragment I have the following code:

```
myViewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    myTextView.text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.my_string, it), FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
}
```

However, when I launch the app the strings are displayed verbatim like this

```
<b>stuff in bold</b> %1$s
```

until the first change of the LiveData is observed and applied. So far I've fixed the issue by immediately sending `""` to all LiveData fields, as if they need to be initialized before being displayed; the result is "**stuff in bold** ", which is what I want before the LiveData receives meaningful updates. Is this the only way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 1 separate method.

```
fun getFormattedString(myString : String) :  String{
  return Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.my_string, myString), FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
}
```

Call this method from onCreate of `activity` or `onViewCreated` of the fragment.

This is for setting `stuff in bold`

```
myTextView.text = getFormattedString(" ")
```

also, do this as well. This is for actual string data from livedata.

```
myViewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    myTextView.text = getFormattedString(it)
}
```

The reason for this is: when we use formatted string, we have to use `Html.fromHtml()` to get the actual formatted string. Layout XML can't get this formatted string from string.xml.

Comment: So it's actually necessary to initialize the formatted strings in some way before they are updated with the new LiveData? Aside from that, the code looks the same as mine and it only encapsulates away the call to `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: Yes, 
and also Since you have used HTML markups, so it is necessary to use it Html.fromHtml()